# Nested functions in parse(eval(...), envir = custom)

Tags: r, environment, scoping, non-standard-evaluation

I have a custom R environment

```
e = new.env()
e[["a"]] = function(x) b(x)
e[["b"]] = function(x) x + 1
```

Function `b()` runs as expected.

```
> eval(parse(text = "b(1)"), envir = e)
[1] 2
```

But `a(1)` throws an error.

```
> eval(parse(text = "a(1)"), envir = e)
Error in a(1) : could not find function "b"
```

How do I get `eval(parse(text = "a(1)"), envir = e)` to work?

Comment: The ideal approach would be to avoid `eval(parse(...))`. What is your actual use case for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that functions in R track the environment in which they were created. When you call the `function()` statement outside of any other context, that function is being created in the global environment, and then you are assigning that function to a different environment, but it doesn't change where it was originally defined. Observe

```
e = new.env()
e[["a"]] = function(x) b(x)

environment(e[["a"]])
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

identical(e, environment(e[["a"]]))
# [1] FALSE
```

So that function will still use the global environment (not the `e` environment) to resolve symbols. You can either explicitly change the environment with

```
environment(e[["a"]]) <- e
```

or just create it in the environment in the first place with `evalq`

```
 evalq(a <- function(x) b(x), e)
 evalq(b <- function(x) x + 1, e)

 identical(e, environment(e[["a"]]))
 # [1] TRUE
```

But are you sure this is really the best design for your problem? Seems a bit obtuse. Seeing `eval(parse())` is usually a warning flag.